# Regex.Split pattern: How to split a string into repeating pattern blocks?

Tags: regex, split

Let's say we have a string:

> "somethinghere%C3somethinghere%83%C3%A8%C3%AF%C3%AD%C3%AEsomethinghere%C3%A7somethinghere"

What would be the Regex.Split pattern to get the following list of values:

1. %C3
2. %83%C3%A8%C3%AF%C3%AD%C3%AE
3. %C3%A7

NOTE: somethinghere - can be any text that has no value and it does not contain the '%' char;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are "somethinghere" the same each time?

Comment: It can be anything, but it will not contain the '%' char;

Comment: What tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Split`. If you want result to be list of strings you could use linq:

```
List<string> result = Regex.Matches(source, "(%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+").OfType<Match>().Select(s => s.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I would assume that's just dummy text, not what would actually be there (update: answer edited since my comment).

Comment: See, I have tied this and Justing's patterns, the result is this:well, I tried these - this the result:     [0]: "somethinghere"
    [1]: "%C3"
    [2]: "somethinghere"
    [3]: "%AE"
    [4]: "somethinghere"
    [5]: "%A7"
    [6]: "somethinghere"

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want:

```
/(%[A-F0-9]{2})+/g
```

Assuming JavaScript-style regex syntax.

### Edit:

If you want to leave the `%` symbol out of the match:

```
/(?:%([A-F0-9]{2}))+/g
```